# Get value from array with php/json

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im trying to read a value of an ajax send jsonarray to base my filename upon but i cant seem to figure out how to read the value.

my php;

```
$postdata = $_POST['data'];

$jsondata = json_decode($postdata);
$myname = $jsondata->name;

$dir = 'users/'.$myname.'/desktop-'.$myname.'.json';
```

json array looks like this;

```
[{"name":"mmichel"},
 {"myicons":
    [{"icon":
       [{"name":"homepagelink","rel":"http://test.tocadovision.nl","id":"icon1","class":"icon bookmark"}]
     },
     {"icon":
       [{"name":"aboutpagelink","rel":"http://test.tocadovision.nl","id":"icon2","class":"icon bookmark"}]
    }]
}]
```

hope someone can tell me what im doing wrong.. must be rly easy i guess

Answer (score 1):

Since `$jsondata` contains an array of one object, you need to access the first element of the array in your assignment:

```
$myname = $jsondata[0]->name;
```

Comment: i thought so too, even before your post, but somehow it isnt :(

Comment: @MartijnMichel - then you need to go through your code and debug each variable until you work out why

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have json enabled in your php config.
You can do this by doing

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

This should output something like this which indicates json module is enabled. If you don't have this enabled, enable it.

[image]

Make sure you have the correct valid json string in $json variable and use one of the following methods.

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($arr[0]['name']);


$arr = json_decode($json);
print_r($arr[0]->name);
```